# How do I go about importing emails from my cPanel export into Gmail Apps for Work?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email, import

Long story short I'm moving my hosting to Digital Ocean from Namecheap, and I paid $15 to get a full export of the cPanel (no longer have access to the hosting account itself so the backup export was my only option), which includes all my emails received on the various accounts.

I want to import these emails into my new Gmail/Google Apps for Work account, but I cannot figure out how to do it. The built in import in Gmail seems to require you to log in to the account or something, but I just have the email files. How do I put them over?

Comment: You can use a client like thunderbird to load the mails and simply drag them to the gmail account.

Comment: What format is the export in? For example, if it's a PST file we can then provide directions specific to importing a PST file into Gmail.